# Screen backlight is Disabled After Installing Nvidia GeForce 9600m GT Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04, brightness, backlight

since several weeks ago, I am in the quest for try to fix the back-light control on my **Sony VGN-AW220j** With **Nvidia GeForce 9600M GT**, but until date no luck after try so many recipes and fixes from many places around the net.

The trouble is that the backlight have no control and always the level is  100% with a great energy waste and great eye hurt and fear for may cause harm too.

i tried `nvidia-bl-dkms` and many other ways.            ....actually no luck at all.

please help...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model and finally corrected a different driver/hardware failure involving the fingerprint reader. After a driver update the computer stopped recognizing the reader. I was just about to return to sony for service after trying to uninstall & revert the driver failed to fix it when I found this fix in amazon customer reviews:

> Power off and disconnect the battery overnight which will require the system to reload all system drivers when you reattach the battery and power it on.

It worked for me and it can't hurt to try for your issue!  I assume you have already used the hdmi output to hook up an external display to then open device manager and open the video display driver adapter and click on the 'uninstall driver' then restart the computer.  This should dislodge the last nvidia driver update that probably caused the display settings failure and reinstall the previous version assuming it worked fine before.

Hope you find this helpful and I'd send it back to sony for service if not. Even at this age they're asking @ $1000. for this laptop. I think it's a great computer so spending some on service & repair might be a good investment. Good Luck!

Comment: I just noticed you appear to have a display, but have lost the ability to lower the brightness. If so, no need for using an external display and everything else still applies. I misunderstood that the display had gone dark after the driver update.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that might work:

First, use this command to get max brightness: `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --get-max-brightness`. Say it gives value `y`.

Second, use this command to set brightness(requires sudo): `sudo /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness x`.

Replace `x` with any value between `0` to `y`.

I have tested it on `Ubuntu 14.04`. Might not work on `Kubuntu`.

**NOTES:**

1. Don't try to use `0` in `x`, you will get a blank screen aka screen with no brightness (Yes, you can type on blank screen in this case).
2. If you don't want to use sudo everytime in 2nd command then type `sudo visudo` and append `%VAR_USER ALL = NOPASSWD:/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper` to sudoers list. (Change `VAR_USER` to your username).

**Warning:** *Be careful when you edit sudoers list if you are not experienced user then don't do it.*